# Timing functions in electron

Tags: javascript, timer, electron, setinterval

I am new to java script and electron. I am trying to code an app that has a start button and a stop button. When the start button is clicked, it is supposed to start a timer that executes a function every so often until the stop button is clicked. After digging a little bit on the internet I found that SetInterval() function should do that. This is the code I have:

```
let timeoutObj;

const startTimer = () => {
    let val = document.getElementById("time-input").value;
    document.getElementById("time-input").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("start-btn").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("stop-btn").disabled = false;
    timeoutObj = setInterval(execution(), val * 10);
}



const stopTimer = () => {
    let val = document.getElementById("time-input").value;
    document.getElementById("time-input").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("start-btn").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("stop-btn").disabled = true;
    stopExecution();
}

const execution = () => {
    console.log('exetuted');
}

const stopExecution = () => {
    console.log('stopping');
    clearInterval(timeoutObj);
}
```

It does not work, it logs "start" once and never does it again. startTimer() and stopTimer() are the onclick functions of the buttons. Can someone explain me why it wont work?
BTW: the value is really low, it should log "start" every 3 seconds.

Comment: Try `setInterval(execution)`, not `setInterval(execution())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascripts setInterval function, expects a function callback as an argument, however you passed the `execution()` effectively executing the function and passing its return value instead of callback.

You should instead do

```
setInterval(execution, val*10) // pass execution callback, instead of calling it
```